# PHP return value within array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to retrieve all the first objects from an array, this is how my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lorem;1;banana
    [1] => ipsum;2;apple
    [2] => dolor;3;grapefruit
    [3] => sit;4;pineapple;
    [4] => amet;5;orange
)
```

I want it to return a certain value of that and store it in a variable, so that I can get all the fruit names, for example. Any way to do this?

Comment: what's your desire output?

Comment: what do you mean by "all the first objects"? there is no objects in your array values. Also, will the fruits always be the last part of the string? I see pineapple has another ; at the end? Does that mean, there could be more strings after the fruits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map`:

```
$fruits = array_map(function($item) {
    $arr = explode(';', $item);
    return $arr[2];
}, $array);

var_dump($fruits);
```

Comment: i think for `[3] => sit;4;pineapple;`  it will return blank

Comment: I didn't saw that.. I've updated the answer.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fruits always come last and may or may not have a trailing semicolon, you can use

- [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) — Perform a regular expression search and replace

**Example:**

```
$data = [
    'lorem;1;banana',
    'ipsum;2;apple',
    'dolor;3;grapefruit',
    'sit;4;pineapple;',
    'amet;5;orange'
];

$fruits = preg_replace('#.+;(.+?)[;]*$#', "$1", $data);

print_r($fruits);
```

The pattern means match everything up and including to a semicolon (greedy), then capture the content up to the end ending with or without a semicolon.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => grapefruit
    [3] => pineapple
    [4] => orange
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk_recursive function and change your array item as per requirement.
use following code which will give you appropriate output:

```
$test = array(0 => 'lorem;1;banana', 1 => 'ipsum;2;apple', 2 => 'dolor;3;grapefruit',3 => 'sit;4;pineapple;',4 => 'amet;5;orange');

array_walk_recursive($test, 'test');
function test(&$item, $key)
{
    $itemArray = explode(';', $item);
    $item = $itemArray[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, those strings can be easily parsed as csv with [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$a = array(
    'lorem;1;banana',
    'ipsum;2;apple',
    'dolor;3;grapefruit',
    'sit;4;pineapple;',
    'amet;5;orange'
);

foreach($a as $line){
    $csvString = str_getcsv($line,';');
    $fruits[] = $csvString[2];
}

print_r($fruits);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => grapefruit
    [3] => pineapple
    [4] => orange
)
```